# Problems with pip install django-socketio

Tags: python, django, socket.io, pip

pip3 install -U django-socketio outputs the following errors python version on this environment is 3.4.3. The same thing appears when I try to install django channels on python 3.5 or higher

```
Collecting django-socketio
  Downloading django-socketio-0.3.9.tar.gz (48kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 204kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-j3y67yvi/django-socketio/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        version = __import__("django_socketio").__version__,
      File "/tmp/pip-build-j3y67yvi/django-socketio/django_socketio/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from django_socketio.utils import NoSocket, send, broadcast, broadcast_channel
      File "/tmp/pip-build-j3y67yvi/django-socketio/django_socketio/utils.py", line 44
        except IndexError, KeyError:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-j3y67yvi/django-socketio/
```

Answer (score 8):

I tried to install it using pip but I was unsuccessful.

What you can do is:
1) download the [Source Code](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio) from GitHub to where you want the files to be

```
git clone https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio
```

2) unzip it and go inside the django-socketio directory
3) run:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

you can check if it has installed by running the command:

```
pip3 freeze
```

hope this helps!

Comment: yeap actually I though about this thing, but I got the same errors with channels on python 3.5,3.6 but on other laptop there is no such problem everything works greate

Comment: You saved it. Thank you.